# jQuery validate(); Only validate on click of one type of submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I have a quite perflexing problem that I have researched and come up blank;

**Scenario:**
I have a form, with the jQuery bassistance.de's validate() plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Does the job on submit perfectly, however; I two types of submit button.

One submits the form as usual, triggering my back-end validation and return errors or success.

The other type, is to all intense and purposes a submit button to the browser, however it tells my back-end to add another section of inputs (ie, a repeating element for employment history.) I want the user to be able to add the repeating elements without having to complete the rest of the form first. So clicking the second type of submit I want to BYPASS the validate();

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="" id="ApplicationForm" name="ApplicationForm">

  <input id="job1" name="job1" class="required"/>
  <input type="submit" name="delete_job1" value="Delete" class="delete" />

  <input id="job2" name="job2" class="required"/>
  <input type="submit" name="delete_job2" value="Delete" class="delete" />

  <input type="submit" name="add_job" value="Add Job" class="add" />

  <input type="submit" name="ApplicationForm" value="Save Details" class="submit" />

</form>
```

I have tried a listener for the true submit button below, but this just stops the validate all togerther;

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var submitPress

    $(".submit").click(function()
    {
        submitPress = true;
    });

    if (submitPress)
    {
        $('form#ApplicationForm').validate();
    }
});
```

I guess this is because the validate(); listeners is setup on the initial loading of the page, not upon submit...

Is there there a rule or setting for validate(); I am missing, that I could utilise, or even a good hack with good old fasioned JS.

Muchos gratias who ever can help, i'm at my whits end.

Yours Sincerely,
Working Late, AGAIN , Developer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Skipping_validation_on_submit

basically, add `class="cancel"` to the submit buttons which you don't want to trigger validation.

```
<input type="submit" value="I Validate" />
<input type="submit" class="cancel" value="I skip Validation" />
```

Comment: Cheers Chris, thats the Badger... Don't know how I missed that.  Think I entered the twilight zone last night and had to go home.

Comment: sweeeet...  using jquery mobile, thought it might be a data-* attribute.  thanks @rambo coder

Comment: As of 2015 the class="cancel" is now deprecated. You now add the 'formnovalidate' attribute. Click on the link to see latest documentation.

Answer (score 0):

its not working,because the id you have provided of your input element,that become change like this `submit_1_btnSubmit` ,after page load

so to get rid this error you may use  `ClientIDMode="Static"`

```
(if you are working on asp.net)
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" CssClass="Submit" ClientIDMode="Static" />

else

you may access `clientIDmode`  property on button control dynamically.
```