# jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.1 Save & Submit Button

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins, form-submit

I am Using jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.1.Here my Web form contains various controls like Text box, dropdown List ,User Controls etc. Each control has validations (Required fields, Emails)
**input id="email" name="email" class="{validate:{required:true,email:true}}"**
Now my page has Save & Submit button, here as per the requirement if the user clicks on save button the user would able to save the form  (incomplete form also) , in this case user should not be prompted for required field(if he is leaving any).The data would save as Draft he may re-continue later but if he Clicks on Submit all validations as tagged with each controls would apply.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $().ready(function () {
            $.validator.setDefaults({
         invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {  }
    });

    var container = $("div.container");

    $("#form1").validate({
        errorContainer: container,
        errorLabelContainer: $("ul", container),
        wrapper: 'li',
        meta: "validate"
    });
});
    </script>
```

Above is the Base validation method written in Master Page.  Any idea how to achieve this???

Answer (score 0):

Set 'Save' button's UseSubmitBehavior property false value

Answer (score 0):

For the save button simply set the class to "cancel" instead of "submit".  This will skip the validation.

Answer can be seen here:

[jQuery validate(); Only validate on click of one type of submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240129/jquery-validate-only-validate-on-click-of-one-type-of-submit-button)

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Skipping_validation_on_submit